# Application of Schwartz Kernel Theorem to Quantum Mechanics

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I am currently reading Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians and have a question about a statement made in the book:

Remark. By the Schwartz kernel theorem, the operator B can be represented by an integral operator with distributional kernel $K(q,q')$. Then the commutativity $BQ = QB$ implies that, in the distributional sense,

$$
(q-q')K(q,q') = 0,
$$

so that $K$ is "proportional" to the Dirac delta-function, i .e., 
$$
K(q,q') = f(q)\delta(q-q'). 
$$
This argument is usually given in physics textbooks.

$B$ and $Q$ are both operators in the coordinate representation. $Q$ is the position operator and $B$ is bounded.

---

So, first of all, I can't find much about the kernel theorem online. [I've been using this as a reference](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1584). According to this document, there is a relation between bilinear forms and distributions. However, I don't know how to view $B$ as a bilinear form and thus apply the theorem. Can someone elucidate how the kernel theorem is applicable to $B$? Secondly, what arguments/notation in physics is the author (of the QM book) referencing?

Comment: What are Q and B here?

Comment: B and Q are both operators in the coordinate representation. Q is the position operator.

Comment: The coordinate representation being the complex square integrable functions on the real line.

Comment: What is B? It seems to have been referenced in something before the remark? Are there any restrictions on the operator B?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to say B is bounded. The preceding lemma says that if B is bounded and if it commutes with Q, then B is a function of Q. I'll make an edit, thanks.

Comment: Bounded in this case means that $B|\psi\rangle \le b|\psi\rangle$ for some constant $b$ and all wavefunctions $|\psi\rangle$, right?

Comment: I think you need to apply the norms to the inequality. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. So it should be $||B|\psi\rangle|| \le b$ for all wavefunctions $|\psi\rangle$ for some $b > 0$.

Comment: on the right it should be, b times the norm of psi.

Comment: Right but I'm assuming the wavefunction is normalized to 1.

Answer (score 3):

If $T$ is a distribution such that $$\forall g \in C^\infty_c, \langle T, x g  \rangle = 0$$ then pick $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ constant $=1$ on $[-1,1]$, let $$g = \frac1x (f-f(0)\phi)\quad\in C^\infty_c$$ then $$ \langle T,f \rangle = \langle T,f(0)\phi \rangle + \langle T,xg\rangle =f(0) \langle T, \phi \rangle$$